# Getting NoClassDefFoundError in jar file

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror, bukkit, spigot

I just added new dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.hamza-cskn.obliviate-invs</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

And now I am getting NoClassDef error. Creator of that library says it is not his fault.

Here's the full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.timuzkas</groupId>
    <artifactId>megabox-clans</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>megabox-clans</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.timuzkas.megaboxclans.Megabox_clans</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>papermc-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>placeholderapi</id>
            <url>https://repo.extendedclip.com/content/repositories/placeholderapi/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>minebench-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.minebench.de/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.destroystokyo.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.MilkBowl</groupId>
            <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.hamza-cskn.obliviate-invs</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.clip</groupId>
            <artifactId>placeholderapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error:

```
[12:55:07 WARN]: Unexpected exception while parsing console command "mtitle menu"
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'mtitle' in plugin megabox-clans v0.4
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:172) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:826) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:788) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:483) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:450) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1416) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1142) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:293) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mc/obliviate/inventory/Gui
        at org.timuzkas.megaboxclans.mtitle.onCommand(mtitle.java:241) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1171]
        ... 9 more
```

Command handler (not full):

```
} else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("menu")) {
                new mtitleGui(Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(sender.getName()).getPlayer(), plugin);
            }
```

GUI class:

```
package org.timuzkas.megaboxclans;

import mc.obliviate.inventory.Gui;
import mc.obliviate.inventory.Icon;
import mc.obliviate.*;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.Configuration;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryCloseEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryOpenEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import java.util.List;

public class mtitleGui extends Gui {

    Megabox_clans plugin;

    public String convertColors(String input) {
        // Convert "&" color codes
        String converted = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', input);

        // Convert hex color codes
        converted = converted.replaceAll("#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6})", ChatColor.COLOR_CHAR + "x$1");

        return converted;
    }

    public mtitleGui(Player player, Megabox_clans plugin) {
        super(player, "mtitle", "Титулы", 6);
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(InventoryOpenEvent event) {
        for (int i = 0; i == 9; i++) {
            if (i == 5) {
                addItem(new Icon(Material.EMERALD).setName("Меню титулов").setLore("Специально для megabox"));
            } else {
                addItem(Material.GRAY_STAINED_GLASS_PANE);
            }
        }
        Icon info = new Icon(Material.PAPER).setName("Информация").appendLore("Титулы можно получать разными способами").appendLore("Получить от админов, купить").appendLore("Получить в розыгрыше").setAmount(1).hideFlags();
        addItem(10, info);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            addItem(19 + i, Material.GRAY_STAINED_GLASS_PANE);
        }
        //--
        Configuration cf = plugin.getConfig();
        List titleslist = plugin.getConfig().getList("players." + player.getName() + ".titleslist");
        for (int i = 0; i < titleslist.size(); i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            addItem(28 + i, new Icon(Material.NAME_TAG).setName(convertColors(cf.getString("titles." + titleslist.get(i) + ".prefix"))).setLore("Клик чтобы установить").onClick(e -> {
                e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();
                Player pl = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(e.getWhoClicked().getName()).getPlayer();
                pl.sendMessage(convertColors("&a&lТитул установлен!"));
                cf.set("players." + pl.getName() + ".set_title", titleslist.get(finalI));
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried One-Jar, but I can't get it to work.

Fix this error. I need it to run from .jar file. I am using PaperSpigot API, IntellijIDEA, Maven, and some dependencies

EDI. Megabox_clans or main class added:

```
package org.timuzkas.megaboxclans;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredServiceProvider;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.timuzkas.megaboxclans.commandtabcompleters.clanCompletion;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public final class Megabox_clans extends JavaPlugin {


    String prefix  = "[MEGABOX | CLANS]";

    private static Economy econ = null;

    public void log(String msg) {
        getLogger().info(msg);
    }

    private boolean setupEconomy() {
        if (getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Vault") == null) {
            return false;
        }
        RegisteredServiceProvider<Economy> rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Economy.class);
        if (rsp == null) {
            return false;
        }
        econ = rsp.getProvider();
        return econ != null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        PluginManager pluginManager = Bukkit.getPluginManager();
        pluginManager.registerEvents(new PlayerLeaveListener(this), this);
        saveDefaultConfig();
        log ("Hooking PAPI...");
        if(Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("PlaceholderAPI") != null) {
            new PAPIExpansion(this).register();
        }
        log("Creating commands...");
        this.getCommand("clan").setExecutor(new Commands(this));
        this.getCommand("tech").setExecutor(new CommandTech(this));
        this.getCommand("mtitle").setExecutor(new mtitle(this));
        this.getCommand("mhec").setExecutor(new CommandProverka(this));
        //- Completers
        this.getCommand("clan").setTabCompleter(new clanCompletion(this));
        //-Economy
        if (!setupEconomy() ) {
            getLogger().severe(String.format("[%s] - Плагин Vault не найден, или нету экономики! Я выключаюсь, бип, боп!!", getDescription().getName()));
            getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
            return;
        }
//--



        File myfile = new File("plugins/Megabox_clans/playerdata.yml");
        if (!myfile.exists()) {
            try {
                myfile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //-----

        File myfile2 = new File("plugins/Megabox_clans/clans.yml");
        if (!myfile2.exists()) {
            try {
                myfile2.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //-----



    }

    public static Economy getEconomy() {
        return econ;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        log("Пока пупсики!");
    }
}
```

I FIXED IT! Idk how, but it now works! Thanks ya` all!

Comment: Do you see that class in the obliviate jar?

Comment: yes, it is here, in mc.obliviate.inventory.Gui

Comment: *Megabox_clans plugin;* We can't test without that. You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but if that class will do it, then you can post that

Comment: You didn't read my comment carefully enough: *but if that class will do it* It *doesn't* do it

Comment: Is this not an MRE?

Comment: No, as it won't compile

Comment: _"Even GPT can't help."_ that is because ChatGPT is nothing more than a convincing bullshit generator. It can generate beautiful text, but a lot of the time it simply comes up with plausible sounding nonsense instead of things actually grounded in reality (or it may have one foot on the ground, and the other foot in Wonderland).

Comment: @AnstonSorensen: that's not how the site works. If the OP does this and you solve the issue, the question will remain unhelpful to future visitors. Better to encourage the OP to fix the question so that it does in fact represent a valid [mre] and so that the code in the question itself shows the source of the error.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well I thought I could answer with the fix to the code if I figured out how to fix it from the jar, but okay

Comment: Are you sure the plugin that as classes `mc.obliviate.inventory` did well started? You can add it in your dependancy in the `plugin.yml`. Also, I suggest you to check for camel case formatting in your naming convention

Comment: @AnstonSorensen where I can send it to you?

Comment: @Elikill58 I am not sure, thats why I ask here this question

Comment: We can't check for you. Check logs of your server and you will see if the plugin that contains it is well loaded

Comment: @Timas_bro Just email me a zip file or jar file at ansorensen1118@gmail.com

Comment: @AnstonSorensen i emailed you

Comment: @Elikill58 it loaded just fine, in the jar all I can find is my classes, plugin and config.yml. I have error message in my question.

Comment: @Timas_bro Yeah, I tested your plugin and I don't get any class not found error. Make sure all your Maven plugins are up to date. I noticed that your Maven Jar plugin is on version 2.4 which was last updated in 2012 lol!

Comment: But yeah when I run /mtitle menu it just sends me a message "huy". Also, keep all your dependencies in the jar after it's built because when I build it there are a bunch of dependencies in the jar, but your jar only has the org.timuzkas. Just want to make sure you're not deleting files or anything

Comment: How to include all dependencies. I tried all day trough. Maven shade, maven jar plugins. I just can't. can you help me? I stuck with this error for weeks.

Comment: @AnstonSorensen and it should open you a GUI. In command class i have that new mtitleGui(Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(sender.getName()).getPlayer(), plugin);

Comment: I fixed it! Finally!